# Coda 2 & Emmet - EOL character displaying

Tags: emmet, coda

I am using emmet with Coda 2, version 2.6.6.  When I use it to create multiple lines, Coda is showing some sort of end of line character.

For instance, if I use `section.container>div*4>{$}`, I get the following:

[image]

At the end of the first three divs is a some sort of EOL character, and I don't know how to get rid of it.  I looked through the editor preferences and did not see anything that would allow me to hide that character.  I've tried it on two different macs and have the exact same results.

Is there a way to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this recently in 2.5.16. it may be related to having mixed line endings.

If you go to Text > Line Endings > Convert to (whatever type of line endings you use), it should clear the symbol.